# When Rigg interrupts his "past" self, why doesn't his current/"future" self disappear?

Tags: pathfinder-series

**Spoilers-ahoy on this one!**

In the *Pathfinder* series of books by Orson Scott Card:

> two of the main characters, Rigg and Umbo, (eventually) have the
>  capability of travelling back in time to interrupt past versions of
>  themselves and therefore altering their past actions. When this
>  happens, the instances of themselves that went back in time
>  "disappear" as they stop existing in this new, altered timeline. Cool.
>  Makes sense. Except *sometimes* when that's *not* what happens!

In *Runes*, the second book, there are a couple instances where this happens in particular:

> At one point, Rigg, Umbo, and Rigg's sister, Param, are arguing on an
>  elevated platform. Rigg pushes Param off the platform and she ends up
>  wounded from the fall. Rigg and Umbo go back in time and stop
>  themselves from triggering this series of events and promptly
>  disappear from existence.

(This is consistent with how it's worked every where else in the two books up to this point and as I described above.)

Later, at the end of the book:

> Rigg kills a dude in a spaceship, which he later regrets. He goes
>  back in time, interrupts himself, and stops past Rigg from killing the
>  dude. You'd think that this would cause "future" Rigg to disappear,
>  but no. They both continue to exist for some reason! They even discuss
>  their new predicament among each other as if it were the normal,
>  expected consequence of the whole ordeal!

Okay, what? Why? If the past and future copies of the characters can exist simultaneously.

Why aren't there two persistent, copied versions of both Rigg and Umbo in my first example?

Is it because Rigg is enhanced by an alien creature at the point in the book where the second example occurs?

Is it because Umbo wasn't present and somehow alters how this metaphysical event happens? Is the dude that got murdered special? The ship? What?

Or is it simply a case of inconsistent lore that requires a retroactive explanation in the third book? (I'm leaning towards this one. OSC's trademark is to whip up some cockamamie nonsense and play it off like it all makes sense when described later.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it because in the past events they only came back as apparitions, warning the version of themselves in that time stream and not really staying in the same time stream with them?  But with the umbo and rigg instances, the original actual jumped and stayed in the same time stream. Just like the 19 ships that started it all?

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Do you have any sources you can cite to support your answer?